# Calculate $ \int_5^9 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}$ by comparison test

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was asked to calculate $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \cfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}$ by comparison test

My problem is that I don't know if I'm understanding right what "calculate" refers to, because for what I know comparison test is useful to conclude about convergence and divergence, but I tried using  this

$\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-25}}$ $\leq$ $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2}}$

And then using $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ as $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{|x|}$

$\Rightarrow$ $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \int_5^9 \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(|x|)$

Finally evaluate from 5 to 9 obtaining $\displaystyle\int_5^9 \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \ln\left(\dfrac{9}{5}\right)$.

But the teacher crossed the answer out but not the procedure, can somebody help me to solve it or fix it because I got curious why it was wrong.

Comment: You increased the denominator, so you got a lower bound not an upper bound

Comment: @RobertTheTutor So then what should I have done?

Comment: Just a hint please

Comment: I very much doubt that you were asked to calculate this by using the comparison test. More likely you were asked to ascertain whether it converges or not by using the comparison test.

Comment: $  \ x^2 - 25 = (x-5)·(x+5) > x-5 \ $ and the integral over the same interval for $ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}} \ \ $ converges as well.  And yes, you will only establish an upper bound, _not_ find a value for your integral.

Comment: The question is written in that way, but yes probably it was just concluding if it converges or diverges

Comment: Also your integrand is _not_ larger than the given integrand over the interval ( 5 , 9] , since $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ $ has its vertical asymptote at $ \ x = 0 \ . $

Comment: I have seen many new teachers make mistakes like this in their phrasing. I highly encourage you to send your instructor an e-mail letting them know that you can either calculate the integral (which doesn’t use the comparison test) or you can check for convergence using the comparison test, but you cannot use the comparison test to calculate an integral. This will help other students in your class as well as future students (if the teacher is receptive of being corrected by a student).

Comment: @Clayton He told me to use comparison test, so check convergence was the right question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is some odd terminology. To compute the integral, we would do a $\cosh$ substitution $x = 5 \cosh u$, which leads us to conclude that the integral is $\cosh^{-1}(\frac{9}{5}) = \ln (\frac{9 + 2 \sqrt{14}}{5})$.

If you are not aware of the $\cosh$ substitution, you would need to do a comparison test to prove the integral converges. Unfortunately, your substitution doesn't actually work, since you provided a lower bound for the function and not an upper bound.

To prove the integral converges, we need to find $f$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 - 25}} \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in (5, 9)$. We would then show that $\int\limits_5^9 f(x) dx$ converges.

The natural choice for $f$ is $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 25}}$, which we can integrate via a $u$-substitution of $u = x^2 - 25$.

Comment: Yes, I show that converges using $x^2−25=(x−5)⋅(x+5)>x−5$ from a comment, so my substitution was wrong, thank you anyway